# How can I deploy an existing installation across multiple ARM devices?

Tags: 14.04, arm, emmc

## Problem Setup

I am working on a home automation system (as a side project), and I plan on using the [Odroid U3](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=g138745696275) running Ubuntu 14.04 in conjunction with [ROS](http://www.ros.org/) to act as individual nodes for this system. Each node will perform different tasks, so the actual source-code housed on each device will be different. For the sake of uniformity, I would like to maintain a single custom image that I could flash on to each device. I'm not too concerned about security for the time being as the project is a demo.

## Questions

- Should I use `dd` to image the eMMC device?
- Follow up on the above, wouldn't this then force me to use the same sized memory device each time?
- Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about a better way, there might be, but dd is good enough, and U3 has a root resize script which can be launched with `/usr/local/bin/odroid-utility.sh`.

PS: Security is not the strongest part of Odroid's boards, so it's a good thing you are not concerned.

Comment: Thanks @mikewhatever, I'll keep you posted if I find a better scheme.